# J/Link: getArray2() returns wrong array

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, java

I want to convert a matrix from Mathematica to an `int[][]` in *Java*.  I use the code below:

```java
KernelLink ml;
ml.evaluate(expr);
int[][] matrix= ml.getIntArray2();
```

As example: if `expr` is `{{1,0},{0,1}}` I get `[[1,0,0,1]]` instead `[[1,0],[0,1]]`.

What's wrong? Did I misunderstand `getIntArray2()`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post a working program so it's impossible to see what you are actually doing. I think you will find that `getIntArray2()` works correctly. Try adding this to your program and you will see the expected output:

```
System.out.println(matrix.length);  // 2
System.out.println(matrix[0][0]);   // 1
System.out.println(matrix[0][1]);   // 0
System.out.println(matrix[1][0]);   // 0
System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);   // 1
```

Comment: I use Eclipse Debugger. I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if I write your code.

Comment: That's because you haven't shown us _your_ code. I expect the problem is in your creation of the value of the variable expr. But until you show an actual working fragment of code, we can only guess at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used the code below:

```java
    //l= number of cols
    int l= Integer.parseInt(ml.evaluateToOutputForm("Length["+x+"[["+1+"]]"+"]",0));
    //s= number of rows
    int s= Integer.parseInt(ml.evaluateToOutputForm("Length["+x+"]",0));
    int[][] matrix=new int[s][l];
    for (int i=1; i<s+1; i++){
         String expr=x+"[["+i+"]]";
         ml.evaluate(expr);
         matrix[i-1]=ml.getIntArray1();
    }
```

I still don't understand how to use `getIntArray2()` and why, for example, this code doesn't work.

```java
    ml.evaluate("{{0,1},{0,0}}");
    int[][] matrix=ml.getIntArray2();
    System.out.println(matrix.length);  // 1
    System.out.println(matrix[0][0]);   // 0
    System.out.println(matrix[0][1]);   // 1
    System.out.println(matrix[1][0]);   //  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);   //  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Comment: Your problems stem from not calling `waitForAnswer()`. The "evaluateToXXX" methods return a result, but when you call `evaluate()`, you must immediately follow it with `waitForAnswer()` if you are planning to read the answer, or `discardAnswer()` if you don't plan to read the answer.

Comment: Your answer is useful, now it works correctly!